# Torrent with different external/local port

Tags: networking, router, bittorrent, nat

I'm running a torrent client behind a router, I want to open the port for the client on the router, but I don't want to use UPnP, so I have to configure NAT.

The problem is that the client sometimes is connected to the LAN with eth0 (cabled), other with wlan0 (wireless), so it may have two different local (static) IP, let's say ip.E and ip.W.

The torrent client is configured on port P (and is always P).

**How configure the NAT, since I cannot address external port P on two different local destinations (ip.E:P and ip.W:P)?**

If I configure two NAT rules

1. externalPortP-to-ip.E:P
2. externalAnotherPort-to-ip.W:P

does the second rule works when the client is connected with the ip.W? Does the torrent client notices that the external port is different from the local one?

Comment: AFAIK your torrent client will still advertise itself on portA whichever interface its connected through so incoming connections from new peers would only work in one scenario.

Comment: @Linef4ult thanks for your comment, so it is as I was expecting, and therefore can not work on the second scenario. Probably the only solution is to configure the same static local IP on both interfaces (eth0 and wlan0) and pay attention to not enable both at the same time, in order to avoid conflicts, right?